# limits.conf not taking effect

Tags: linux, oracle

I have been trying to open oracle db. It gives below error.

> ORA-27515: inadequate memlock limit

So I put below lines in `limits.conf`.

```
*   soft   memlock    60397977
*   hard   memlock    60397977
```

However even after reboot, it doesn't take effect.

Both these files contains below line `./etc/pam.d/su` and `/etc/pam.d/sshd`:

```
session    required     pam_limits.so
```

Comment: First hit when I searched for this [suggested a different PAM file may need to be changed?](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-security-4/setting-memlock-with-limits-conf-933836/) Off-topic for this site though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out that UsePam was set 'no' in /etc/ssh/sshd_config file.
I made it 'yes', rebooted the node and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Add:
`UsePAM yes` to your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`
and
You don't need to reboot. Just restart `sshd` service.

You restart by one of the following commands:
**Debian/Ubuntu**

- `sudo systemctl restart ssh.service`
  OR
- `sudo systemctl restart ssh`

**Red Hat/CentOS**

- `sudo systemctl restart sshd.service`
  OR
- `sudo systemctl restart sshd`

**macOS**

- `sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist` then `sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist`

**FreeBSD/OpenBSD**

- `/etc/rc.d/sshd restart`

Credit GH P's answer of adding UsePAM=yes to sshd_config.